# How do I get the <picture> element to show the right image on mobile?

Tags: html, image, mobile

here is my html code

```html
<picture>
    <source
        media="(max-width: 980px)"
        src="/public/images/logo_small.png">
    <img src="/public/images/logo_resized.png">
</picture>
```

I cannot get the `logo_small.png` image to load when on mobile. Am I missing something obvious here ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be min width not max:

```
<picture>
    <source
        media="(min-width: 980px)"
        src="/public/images/logo_small.png">
    <img src="/public/images/logo_resized.png">
</picture>
```

Try that.

Comment: Thks for you ranswer but no change.
Just to clarify I would like logo_small to appear when the user is on mobile and logo_resized in other cases.